# Mysql conditional MAX or MIN dependent on another column value

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I want to run a MYSQL query that gets the MAX of one column OR the MIN of the same column, conditional on the value of ANOTHER column. For example, say my table is of:

ID , Gender , Score

Gender could be "boy" or "girl" and I wish to query the aggregated MAX score for girls and the MIN score for boys

I don't want to run complicated JOINS or multiple queries "where ID in...."  as this is already only part of a more sophisticated query with JOIN and I try to avoid performance issues.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT  ... list of columns ...                     
    DB_User_ID ,                            
    DB_Gender ,
    IF(DB_Gender ='girl', MAX(DB_Score), 0) AS Max_Girls_Score,
    IF(DB_Gender ='boy', MIN(DB_Score), 0) AS Min_Boys_Score,
    FROM DB
    JOIN .... and continue of query ....
    GROUP BY DB_User_ID
```

The above query won't work properly because if DB_Gender = 'girl' obviously Min_Boys_Score will be zeroed and vice versa. Question is - is there any logical work around this query to run the MAX condition ONLY for Girls and the MIN only for boys?

Logically, what I'm trying to achieve (see below) is:

```
SELECT .....
IF(DB_Gender ='girl', MAX(DB_Score) AS Max_Girls_Score, MIN(DB_Score) AS Min_Boys_Score)
```

But this is not a legit MYSQL query

************* I MANAGED TO SOLVE THIS, here is a simple solution: ****************

The select would have a conditional if:

```
SELECT {column list}
    IF(DB_Gender ='girl', MAX(DB_Score), MIN(DB_Score)) AS Min_Max_Scores
......
```

then added another GROUP BY the conditional field:

```
GROUP BY DB_User_ID, DB_Gender
```

The outcome are all the rows, grouped by gender, while then Min_MAx_Scores will be either MAX or MIN dependent with the gender

********* Another solution that I managed to figure out ****************

```
SELECT ......
SUM(IF(DB_Gender ='girl',MAX(DB_Score),0) AS Max_Girls_Score,
SUM(IF(DB_Gender = 'boy',MIN(DB_Score),0) AS Min_Boys_Score
```

this will sum the max score for girls and the min score for boys

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column you use to drive the condition is binary, you can get around this by combining the IFs together, like this:

```
SELECT  ... list of columns ...                     
DB_User_ID ,                            
DB_Gender ,
IF(DB_Gender ='girl', MAX(DB_Score), MIN(DB_Score) AS Score,
FROM DB
JOIN .... and continue of query ....
GROUP BY DB_User_ID
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. Is it possible to do -

IF(DB_Gender ='girl', MAX(DB_Score) AS Max_Score, MIN(DB_Score) AS Min_Score)

?

I'm trying this now

Comment: So.... your answer is great, thanks for the prompt reply @nickhamlin - however -

I wish to seperate between the Max scores and the Min scores as those will be used for girls and for boys. This is not legit MYSQL query:

IF(DB_Gender ='girl', MAX(DB_Score) AS Max_Girls_Score, MIN(DB_Score) AS Min_Boys_Score) but that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you *only* want those attributes, you can try:

select MAX(if(DB_Gender='girl', DB_Score, 0)) AS MaxGirlScore,
       MIN(if(DB_Gender='boy', DB_Score, 10000000)) as MinBoyScore 
From DB

Caveats:
If you are trying to get the max/min for each girl/boy, and you have multiple scores per user, this is not quite what you want.  Notice the above does not apply any group-by semantics.